# Reverse engineering and patching of iOS app (IPA file)

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, patch, ipa, ida

For my master thesis I am working on reverse engineering a IPA file, since I'm new to this topic I'm open on all kind of suggestions. If anyone has any good tutorial or readings or just some personal knowledge to share with me, I would really appreciate it.

Long story short, I must:

- RE the IPA: for this I'm focusing on two tools, **IDA Pro** (that isn't free) and **Radare2** (open source).
- Patch the RE app: I need to find specific **safety checks** (e.g. login, jailbreak, etc.), change the specific check in such a way that it returns the value I want.
- Install the modified IPA on a jailbroken device to see that what I did worked :D

As I said, I am not expecting any ready-to-go solution for this question, instead I just would like to have some hints that could bring me on the right learning tracks.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Broad, open-ended questions aren't a good format for this site, so this will likely end up being closed. But the [reverse engineering subreddit](https://reddit.com/r/reverseengineering) may be useful to you. If you come up with any specific questions along the way, feel free to ask those here, or better yet, at the [Reverse Engineering StackExchange site](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com). Good luck!

Comment: First sorry for the late reply, I could not reply earlier.
I am currently using another approach described in this book :

[link](https://github.com/iosre/iOSAppReverseEngineering.git)